# Erro: Variables debug info not available

Tags: android, android-studio, debug, kotlin

Sempre que tento "debugar" com o Android Studio esse erro aparece:

"variables debug info not available".

Código no gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "br.com.appunivespcurso"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    compile 'com.android.support:support-compat:27.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:27.0.0'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Comment: Sempre? Se você criar um projeto novo agora e tentar depurar dá o mesmo erro?

Comment: Interessante, não pensei nisso, testei agora com um outro projeto qualquer e funcionou normalmente.

Comment: Você está usando o *build variant* padrão? Se tiver criado um novo, precisa colocar `debuggable true` explicitamente.

Comment: Desconheço  "build variant"...

Comment: Dê uma olhada nos seus build.gradle . Você vai encontrar uma parte que diz `buildTypes`. Edite a pergunta com o que está lá, por favor.

Comment: Desculpa, eu não entendi, devo colocar o código que está no buildTypes na pergunta?

Comment: Isso. Deve ser algo do tipo `buildTypes { debug { .... } release { ..... } ........ }`. Pode colocar o build.gradle inteiro também (do módulo em questão, ou todos).

Comment: release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
deveria existir a variante de debug tbm. O debug é feito no buildType de debug. Se vc adicionar : 
debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

deve funcionar